# Where can I get some source code for the earth/globe to integrate into my android application?

Tags: android

I am new to android developing...

I am looking to work on a globe application, where the aim is to show some information when someone touches/selects a country.

For that I need a globe/earth map, it must be developed in a technology supported by android.

Where should I be looking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check out this link,,i think it may help you..

[How to render an interactive globe/earth for the iPhone OpenGL ES?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322111/any-one-know-of-an-opengl-es-example-of-an-interactive-globe-earth-for-the-iphon)

[Spinning globe in Opengl-es](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811082/spinning-globe-in-opengl-es)

[Drawing a Globe with OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987541/drawing-a-globe-with-opengl-es)

Comment: This is what you have suggested, I think for Ios environment, i am looking for something suitable to android platform.. If there is any technique to integrate c/c++/objective-c code in android application then let me know also.